# Display Datalabel for an specific point in Chart Js

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to build a chart.js Line and with scatter points and I would like to have the datalabel to show just on the scatter points, I've tried to do it with datalabels plugin from chart js but it  shows the datalabel for all datasets including the line, How can I show just the specific scatter points? this is what the code looks like:

```
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

        fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConeDigital/assets/main/data.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d'),
                chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: getChartData(data),
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                         plugins: {
                                datalabels: { // This code is used to display data values
                                    anchor: 'end',
                                    align: 'top',
                                    font: {
                                        weight: 'bold',
                                        size: 16
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        tooltips: {
                            mode: 'index',
                            intersect: false,
                            callbacks: {
                                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                    return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItem.yLabel+"%";
                                },
                                labelColor: function (tooltipItem, chart) {
                                    let border = ''
                                    let background = ''
                                    let colors
                                    if ( tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 1 ) {
                                        colors = {
                                            borderColor: '#fff',
                                            backgroundColor: '#001F5B'
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        colors = {
                                            borderColor: '#fff',
                                            backgroundColor: '#eb8484'
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return colors
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        responsive: true,
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                stacked: false,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: false,
                                    labelString: 'Datum'
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    display: false
                                },
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false,
                                    drawBorder: false,
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                stacked: false,
                                ticks: {
                                    display: false
                                },
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false,
                                    drawBorder: false
                                },
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: false,
                                    labelString: 'Procent'
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
        })
        
        

        function getChartData(json) {
            var labels = [];
            
            var omx_dataset = {
                label: 'OMXS30',
                borderColor: '#eb8484',
                fill: false,
                pointRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: []
            };

            var gadd_dataset = {
                label: "GADD SMP SEK",
                borderColor: '#001F5B',
                fill: false,
                pointRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: []
            };
            
        var mark1_dataset = {
                  label: 'Start',
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: '#FF0000',
                  fill: false,
                  type: 'scatter',
                  data: [{
                   x: '2011-03-29',
                   y: 0
                  }],
                 
                  pointRadius: 12
                };
                
        var mark2_dataset = {
                  label: '2016',
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: '#FF0000',
                  fill: false,
                  type: 'scatter',
                  data: [{
                   x: '2015-12-31',
                   y: 20
                  }],
                  
                  pointRadius: 12
                };  

          var mark3_dataset =   {
                  label: '2020',
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: '#FF0000',
                  fill: false,
                  type: 'scatter',
                  data: [{
                   x: '2020-01-07',
                   y: 59
                  }],
                  
                  pointRadius: 12
                };  

          var mark4_dataset =   {
                  label: '2022',
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: '#FF0000',
                  fill: false,
                  type: 'scatter',
                  data: [{
                   x: '2022-01-03',
                   y: 109
                  }],
                  
                  pointRadius: 12
                };                      
            
            json.map((point,i) => {
                labels.push(point.Date)
                const gadd_num = (point['GADD SMP SEK']*100).toFixed(2)
                const omx_num = (point['OMXS30']*100).toFixed(2)
                gadd_dataset.data.push(gadd_num)
                omx_dataset.data.push(omx_num)
                
                //console.log(point.Date)
                //result1_dataset.data.push(point.date)

            })

            return {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [omx_dataset, gadd_dataset, mark1_dataset, mark2_dataset, mark3_dataset, mark4_dataset]
            }
        }
```

Right now it shows all the datalabels from all the datasets and it looks messed up,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the datalabels config to the line datasets, disabling the plugin, as the following:

```
var omx_dataset = {
     label: 'OMXS30',
     borderColor: '#eb8484',
     fill: false,
     pointRadius: 0,
     borderWidth: 1,
     data: []
      
     datalabels: {
       display: false
     }
};

var gadd_dataset = {
     label: "GADD SMP SEK",
     borderColor: '#001F5B',
     fill: false,
     pointRadius: 0,
     borderWidth: 1,
     data: [],
      
     datalabels: {
       display: false
     }
};
```